# Allowing flexible width during element initiation but fixed thereafter, using CSS only

Tags: html, css

Is it possible, using only `CSS`, to allow for an element to have an undetermined flexible width when it is first rendered by the browser, but then immediately make its width fixed so it doesn't change anymore?

I'll clarify with an example.

Let's say there is an simple element as such:

```
<p>Some text</p>
```

As the browser renders the element, it gives it a certain width. Now let's say that instead of Some text, there is some sort of dynamically injected value in the element:

```
<p>{{value}}</p>
```

When the page first renders, `value="Short string"`, but later on value changes to `value="a much longer string is now used"`.

Is it possible to have the width of the element calculated by the content at the initiation, but fixed after any changes? Without using any `Javascript`.

- at start:

```
|Short string|
```

- later:

```
|a much      |
|longer      |
|string is   |
|used this   |
|time around |
```

- or if reversed:

```
|a much longer string is used this time|
```

```
|Short String                          |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some hacks you can approximate this. The trick is to have a hidden text defining the space then all the visible text will consider that space.

Example:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.box:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  opacity: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

.box span {
  width:0;
  min-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" data-text="intial text"><span>intial text</span></div>
<br>
<div class="box" data-text="intial text"><span>A very long text later</span></div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="box" data-text="an initial very long text"><span>an initial very long text</span></div>
<br>
<div class="box" data-text="an initial very long text"><span>short txt later</span></div>
```

Comment: I left this open for possible further answers. Your "hack" solution is nice i like it.